# Jasper Report| I want to add line from column details to column footer and footer should not be float jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to make a invoice report such as:

[image: invoice]

and currently i am working on it it is like this.

[image: missing lines]

Answer (score 0):

Create a subreport to act as a layer that contains the parallel lines, such as:

[image: background lines]

By itself, this produces:

[image: Rendered lines]

In the main report, update the **Background** layer to use the subreport:

[image: background layer]

This then can produce:

[image: output]

The header and footer must be at a fixed location in the master template, relative to the full page height.